# Implement random forest without bootstrap

Tags: r, random-forest

I want to implement the random forest algorithm of Breiman (2001) using all my training set to grow the trees. In other words, I want to keep the random selection of inputs at each node and remove the bootstrap stage. This is motivated by the fact that I'm working with few observations that exhibit auto-correlation.

I've gone through the documentation of the packages `randomForest`, `ranger` and `Rborist`, but I didn't find an answer. I've also tried to take a look at the source code of the function `randomForest` using `getAnywhere(randomForest.default)`; but I have to admit that my R-level is too low to be able to get anything out of it.

Thank you in advance.

Edit. Note to future readers: if you want to modify the bootstrap step, make sure to set `keep.inbag=T` when using `randomForest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sampsize argument in randomForest controls the number of samples used for each tree and the replace argument controls whether or not you are bootstrapping. So in your case, set sampsize=N (number of samples) and replace=FALSE.

Comment: I've just tried to implement the forest with, `replace=F` and `sampsize=N`, this resulted in NaN values for `predicted`  and thus for `mse`. How to explain it ?

Comment: I'm assuming you replaced N with the actual number of samples you have?

Comment: Are you using the strata option?

Comment: I replaced N by `nrow(data.train)`.
I'm not using the strata option.

Comment: Can you paste your code? If by NaN values for predicted you mean that you called predict(model), then that makes sense because those are computed using out-of-bag samples which you have 0 of since every observation is used in every tree.

Comment: This makes sense. I tried to use the rf to predict values for the test set and it seems to have worked.